# Issues when upgrading support library to v28 or androidx

Tags: android, android-appcompat, dagger-2, android-databinding, androidx

I am working on an Android project where I use:

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle 3.1.3
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin 1.2.50
com.google.gms:google-services 3.2.0

compileSdkVersion 27
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 27 

com.google.dagger:dagger  2.12
com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support 2.12
com.android.support:appcompat-v7 27.1.1
```

The project is made using Kotlin and Databinding.

If I upgrade compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 28, project gets compiled.

But then when I try to upgrade to Androidx or AppCompat Library V7 28.0.0 and after fixing all dependencies, I usually end up getting following errors:

```
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class SomeProjectClassBinding
  e: /Users/a/project/databinding/SomeProjectClassBinding.java:76: 
  error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) { ...
```

I tried several things, including:

- Using kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler" and also not using it. By default I have not that line since I read it is already included in Android Studio 3.2.
- Although I am using Android Studio 2.3, I tried 3.3 Canary 13.
- I tried upgrading com.android.tools.build:gradle to 3.3.0-alpha13
- I tried removing org.gradle.jvmargs from gradle.properties.
- I tried upgrading ext.kotlin_version to 1.2.71
- I tried running gradle from terminal, so I can get the dependencies trees but I couldn't find anything inusual.
- I tried to clean and rebuild project.

After upgrading all project's dependencies to the latest version, I do not get any warning from Android Studio but the project doesn't compiles because the error mentioned above.

So, is there anything I can do to know more why I am getting this databinding error ?, is there a sample project published where it is using:

- Latest version of Android API, i.e. 28
- Latest version of Support Library or Jetpack
- Latest version of Dagger
- Databinding
- Kotlin

Also, do we know if the latests version of these are compatible with each other, like Android API 28 or Androidx with Dagger 2.17.

Comment: A lame question from me, but have you tried `clean + rebuild` after updating the target SDK version and support libs?

Comment: Thanks for reading it, yes I did that. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: One clue: Dagger 2.17 isn't compatible and it'll cause the `DataBindingComponent` problem. https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1245

Comment: Dagger 2.17 is not compatible with Androidx nor support library v28 ?, I just found that there are a couple of mentions of Dagger not to be compatible with Androidx in its [release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/androidx-rn#1.0.0a1-ki), although there are people claiming [it is compatible](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/8jb4ax/til_dagger_216_is_out_with_androidx_compatibility/) but I don't find anything about support library v28.

Comment: Working fine for me after downgrading Dagger to 2.16